# Read specific characters in text files within a directory and write the content to another text file

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and face with the dilemma on how to **extract specific characters** from text files in a folder into **another text file** separated by a comma. I am **Using a console application**. The txt files looks like below

```
12345 678910111212 AB123 167898778 XXXX 000000GHZ00000 12
02345 678910111213 CB123 167898779 SSSSS 000000GHZ00000 10
22345 678910111214 FBH123 167898772 PTT 000000GHZ00000 09
32345 678910111215 WB123 167898773 PPP 000000GHZ00000 11
42345 678910111216 ZBW123 167898779 E 000000GHZ00000 01
```

I am able to read all the files into one text file but it makes the file too big. I would like to just extract the records I need to the text file. Trim the white spaces and to write to the new text file, formatted as below.

```
AB, 678910111212, 167898778, 12, GHZ
CB, 678910111213, 167898779, 10, GHZ 
FB, 678910111214, 167898772, 09, GHZ 
WB, 678910111215, 167898773, 11, GHZ 
ZB, 678910111216, 167898779, 10, GHZ
```

Anyone help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use Split, Substring and String interpolation.  If you want specific help you need to show a specific attempt

Comment: Iterate file and use string.split with option of remove empty entires(will trim extra spaces) method like str.Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) and then push in to array

Comment: Also, there seems to be a typo in your expected output.  Specifically the last line: `ZB, 678910111216, 167898779, 10, GHZ` The `10` should be a `01` right?

Answer (score 1):

This feels like homework, and I don't do other folks' homework, but, I can help:

1. Open the file like you are doing
2. Instead of reading the whole file in, read it line by line.  If you really want to read it in whole, use `File.ReadAllLines()` to get a string array, and then `foreach` over the array.  If the file is *very* long, you are better off reading in a line, writing out a line, repeat.
3. Open another file for writing, when you finish with every line, you will write to that file.
4. On every line, use `string.Split` (using a space as the split character if the input always uses a space to separate the columns, use `null` if you want to split on any whitespace) to split the lines into an array of strings.  The 0-element will be the four digit number, the 1-element, the long number, etc.
5. On the third element (element #2), use `string.Substring` to extract the first two characters.  Now you have all your parts
6. Use "string interpolation" (`$"{substringOfLetters}, {myArray[1]}, etc"`) to build your output line
7. Write that output line to that second file
8. When you finish looping, close both files.